Jer. 46:11 — “virgin”
Jeremiah 46:11 in some English versions contains the word “virgin” and others omit it.  The Hebrew בּתוּלה according to a couple of lexicons can mean virgin but also can mean other things.  What makes virgin the correct/incorrect interpretation, or what justifies eliding the word completely?
In a Portuguese version (NTLH)  and in a Dutch version (HTB), the phrase used translates to “people of Egypt.”  In Italian (ICL), I see "inhabitant of Egypt" and in Spanish (NVI), "virgin daughter of Egypt."  One modern Greek version (TGV) says “άθλια, ελεεινή Αίγυπτος” which Google translates as “wretched, pitiful Egypt.”

The operative word in Jer 46:11 is בְּתוּלָה (bethulah) - this occurs 50 times in the OT and is uniformly rendered "virgin", eg, Gen 24;16, Ex 22;16, 17, Lev 21:3, 14, Deut 22;19, 23, 28, 32:25, Judges 19:24, 21:12, 2 Sam 13:2, 18, 1 Kings 1:2, 2 Kings 19:21, etc, etc.
Among the modern versions, only the paraphrastic versions omit it by translating "virgin" as "people" or equivalent such as: CEV, GWT, GNT, NET, etc.  This is a minority of versions.  Most translate the word literally as "virgin".
The LXX also uses παρθένῳ θυγατρὶ = "virgin daughter" - see Appendix 2 below.
APPENDIX 1 - "Maiden"
There is another "famous" word עַלְמָה (almah) = "maiden" which occurs only seven times in the OT at Gen 24:43, Ex 2:8, Ps 68:25, Prov 30:19, SS 1:3, 6:8, Isa 7:14.  It is the last of these that has caused a translation debate - should it be "maiden", or "virgin", as it is quoted in Matt Matt 1:23?  That is a question for another day.
APPENDIX 2 - Jeremiah in LXX
The LXX is rather tricky in the book of Jeremiah.  The following is taken from  www.ellopos.net
Thus, in Rahlf's LXX, Jer 46:11 is Jer 26:11 in the LXX.


Let's see how Jewish scholars before the time of Christ interpreted Jeremiah 46:11.
The Greek Septuagint translation was created by Jewish scholars under the auspices of the Sanhedrin, the highest legislative and judicial assembly of ancient Israel. There was a need to make the Tanakh accessible to Greek-speaking people--for example, it's estimated that there were a million Greek-speaking Jews in Alexandria, Egypt at that time.
The Septuagint dates back to the third and second century before Yeshua of Nazareth. Thus, we are able to get a snapshot in time to how בְּתוּלַ֖ת (bethulah, SH 1330) in the text was interpreted at that time. In this Greek translation, Jeremiah 46:11 reads literally as follows:

Ascend to Gilead, and take the balm to the virgin daughter of Egypt.
In vain you multiplied your cures - a benefit there is not to you.

The word for virgin in Greek is παρθένω (SG 3933), which means a woman who has never had sexual relations. This is the Greek word that these pre-Christian Jewish scholars chose in interpreting the original Hebrew.
Why any English translators chose a different word might have to do with the source documents they used. I don't know. Unfortunately, Jeremiah 46:11 is missing from the Dead Sea Scrolls.
Hope this helps.

There is no evidence that the extant Greek translation of Jeremiah predates Jesus or was done under the permission of the great Sanhedrin

Of course there is, @Avi. Simply look up the estimated date that the Septuagint was completed (Torah was completed first). Yeshua began his ministry about 27 CE.

After considering it a bit more, I can see that the text is (likely) not referring to a single virgin female but is likely a metaphor for the general population of Egypt.

After more consideration, I believe that the text is (likely) not referring to a single virgin female but is a metaphor for the general population of Egypt.  At least that would explain any of the varying renderings I’ve read.
